# App getting heavy while saving data to iphone directory,,,

Tags: iphone, image

I am saving data to iphone directory which i have created, in PNG format,,,but my app getting heavier, 
what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the choices are fairly obvious: either delete data from the documents directory that you don't need anymore, or use a file format with more compression than PNG (eg, lossy JPEG). You'll have to make a compromise somewhere, so it's about what's better for you app: more compression on the images, or keeping lossless images but automatically deleting (or offering users the option to manually delete) files older than a certain date, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not releasing used memory (such as images, view, etc). Try running your application with `Build & Analyze`.